# How can I disable ducking for all voice-overs in iMovie?

Tags: audio, imovie

On my videos I always do voice-overs where I keep the other audio tracks at full volume (no ducking). I know how to set the ducking for individual voice-over clips, but this takes about six extra mouse-clicks for each voice-over and is a royal PITA. Is there a hidden preference somewhere or another way in iMovie to default voice-overs to not duck other audio?